# In Coq, how to define a set like A = {x | f(x) = 0}?

Tags: coq

I am a newbie in using Coq. I want to ask if I want to define a set like 
`A = {x | f(x) = 0}`,
how could I do that? 
I write something like:

```
Definition f0 := nat->nat. 

Definition A : Set := 
  forall x, f0 x -> 0.
```

They are not working as expected.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

More or less like you wrote.  First, you have to have some function `f0 : nat -> nat` that you want to apply this definition to.  What you did here

```
Definition f0 := nat -> nat.
```

was to name the type `nat -> nat` of functions from naturals to naturals `f0`. You probably had in mind something like this:

```
Variable f0 : nat -> nat.
```

This declares a variable `f0` that belongs to the type `nat -> nat`.  Now we can adapt your original description to Coq code:

```
Definition A : Set := {x : nat | f0 x = 0}.
```

There are two things to be aware of here.  First, you might want to apply this definition later to a *particular* function `f0 : nat -> nat`, such as the predecessor function `pred : nat -> nat`.  In this case, you should enclose your code in a section:

```
Section Test.
Variable f0 : nat -> nat.
Definition A : Set := {x : nat | f0 x = 0}.
End Test.
```

Outside of the section, `A` is actually a function `(nat -> nat) -> Set`, that takes a function `f0 : nat -> nat` to the type `{x : nat | f0 x = 0}`.  You can use `A` as you would use any other function, e.g.

```
Check (A pred).
(* A pred : set *)
```

The second thing you must keep in mind is that a `Set` in Coq is not the same thing as a set in conventional mathematics.  In math, an element of the set `{x | f(x) = 0}` is also an element of the set of natural numbers. But not in Coq. In Coq, you need to apply an explicit projection function `proj1_sig` to convert an element of `{x : nat | f0 x = 0}` to a `nat`.

Comment: Thanks very much, this is so perfect! :)