# How to define an affine set in coq

Tags: coq

Ultimately I am trying to work my way towards defining an affine set in R^n. But to start I'm trying to work with points in QxQ with coefficients in Q.
I want to define C a subset of QxQ as affine if for any x,y in C and t in Q, tx+(1-t)y is in C.

I read the answer to [In Coq, how to define a set like A = {x | f(x) = 0}?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045763/in-coq-how-to-define-a-set-like-a-x-fx-0) which I think helped but I would need something more like C = { x | x = t1 * x1 + t2 * x2   where x1,x2 in C /\ t1 + t2 = 1}.

Comment: Don't you mean "convex set"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between what you have and your linked question with `A = {x | f(x) = 0}` is that you aren't defining a single subset. Instead, you should define subsets in general then introduce a predicate to determine if a given subset is affine.

Let's start with what you want the definition to be.

> I want to define C a subset of QxQ as affine if for any x,y in C and t in Q, tx+(1-t)y is in C.

So we should be given a subset `C` and say (informally still) `IsAffine C := forall (x y: C) (t: Q), t * x + (1 - t) * y: C`. This is pretty close to formal, though it uses some set theory conventions. The main one is that we don't prove that a given element is in a given type: the element has a fixed type whenever it's defined.

Really what we're saying here is that we have some notion of what it means for an element of `R^n` to be in the subset `C`. In fact, that's a perfectly good definition of subset: `Subsets R^n := R^n -> Prop`, that is, a subset is a function that takes a point and returns a proposition, which may or may not be true, depending on whether the point is in the subset. This is analogous to the powerset of a set `X` being `2^X` in set theory, except we use `Prop` instead of `2`.

Then to quantify over all the elements of a subset `C: R^n -> Prop`, we do something like `forall x: R^n, C x -> ...`, which could be read as "for all x in R^n, if x is in C, then ...".

So here's how I'd formalize what you want (given a definition of `Q` and definitions of scalar multiplication and vector addition).

```
Definition Subsets (A: Type) := A -> Prop.

Definition IsAffine (C: Subsets (Q * Q)) :=
  forall (x y: Q * Q), C x -> C y -> forall t: Q, C (t * x + (1 - t) * y).
```